# css. How to write (code) css for different window widths?

Tags: css, responsive-design

Want to know correct (the best) way how to write (code) css for different window widths.

Here is live example https://jsfiddle.net/q0ony7Lb/16/

For example, have left, right sidebars and main content (`#middle`).

```
<div id="left">Content in left div<br/></div>    

<div id="middle">Content in middle div<br/></div>

<div id="right">Content in right div<br/></div>
```

If widow width is less or equal to `400px`, then want to show only `#middle`.

If width more than `400px` and less than or equals to `700px`, then display `#middle` and `#left`.

If width more than `700px`, then display all.

At the moment doing in such way:

1) write default css (as understand "default" css applies if no other rules inside corresponding `@media screen`). Default css like

```
#left {background-color:#fff; background-repeat:repeat; background-position:left top; width:180px; height:25px; font-size:16px; font-family:Verdana; color:black; border-style:solid; border-width:1px; border-color:#000; text-align:left; padding:0px 0px 0px 0px; }
```

2) For certain window width write special css rules. Like

```
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
#left, #right { display:none}
#middle { width:350px; height:75px; }    
}

@media screen and (min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 700px) {
#right { display:none}
}
```

As result, for example, if window width is less or equals to `400px` then hide both sidebars and `#middle` resizes.

As i see applies css values from "default" and if inside `@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {` exists different values from "default", then applies different values (different values change "default" values).

Seems all works. But may be some better way how to do all?

Another way may be to write (repeat) whole rules for each width of window. And do not write "default" values. But in such case code would be longer....

Comment: What is your question? That's basically how you do it, yes.

Comment: I prefer `jquery` for animational webpage. But if only simple `css` will be changed, I think `@media` is best. However `bootstrap` is powerful `css` library too

Comment: @torazaburo Question is "if the way how i do it, is ok?" Just want to check. Wrote several variations and seems a little mess in my head. So want to check how to do it better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One suggestion in the above code.

Since `#right { display:none}` applies for all widths less than 700, you can add it in `@media (max-width:700px)`.

Use `max-width` media queries in descending order and keep changing the styles for the lower width screens.

https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/q0ony7Lb/17/

Comment: I see you use only `max-width`. Also all works. So i understand that i need not to use `(min-width: Xpx) and (max-width: Xpx)`. `(max-width: Xpx)` is enough. If window width is between `401px` and `700px`, then applies `@media (max-width:700px){`?

Comment: You can use min and max range. keep it as last priority. Also you can try  all `min-width`  in ascending order, to style from small screen to large. Using `max-width` in descending order, it works from large screen to small.